# Changing button color by clicking another button during runtime in visual basic?

Tags: c#, vba, winforms, runtime

I created a new button object inside a button click. Now want to change the color of the button after being clicked by another button.

I created a button object named that as "btnBlank", gave that a Name as "btnBlank" similarly, set a specific point of location, gave that a size, then wanted to gave the button a color. but couldn't find a way.

```
        private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //  **** create a blank button(by btn object) ****
              Button btnBlank = new Button();      
              btnBlank.Name = "btnBlank";         
              btnBlank.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50,50);     
              btnBlank.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70,30);         
              //Color redColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
              btnBlank.BackColor = new System.Drawing.Color(redColor);    // here's the problem

              panel2.Controls.Add(btnBlank);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `struct Color` have already initialised some of the predefined colors as static members.
Simply do:

```
btnBlank.BackColor = Color.Red
```

More [info about Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netframework-4.8).